# Solving an acyclic maze on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to find an algorithm that will always solve a randomly generated, acyclic maze, I'm using the following code but it keeps getting stuck. Any suggestions?

```
function makeMove()
{   
    if(isWall("Right") == true)
    {
        move("Forward");
    }
    else if(isWall("Right") == false)
    {
        move("Right");
    }
    else if(isWall("Right") == true && isWall("Forward") == true)
    {
        move("Left");
    }
}
```

Comment: Make it random, it will solve it eventually :)

Comment: The maze is randomly generated with this code

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking for the non-existence of a wall? The problem here is that you are going to need to do some type of path tracking

Comment: Your third case will never resolve since one of the first two are always matched... that's the beauty of a boolean.

Comment: this code is attempting to solve a randomly generated maze, but it is not supposed to require checking for the existence of a wall, rather just following the right wall of the maze until it eventually reaches the end

Comment: What happens when you go forward, then, there is a wall forward, right, and left? How do you go backward?

Comment: So it's not a true maze, it's just a path that can go left, right, or forward...

Comment: What I see here is the inability to backtrack... that's probably what's getting you stuck.

Comment: There are points in the maze where there is a wall to the left forward and right of the cursor, but wouldn't the final conditional in this code make the cursor just turn to the right and thus get out of the three-walled piece of the maze?

Comment: Well, first correct your algorithm as stated by @BenStephenson. Your third case never gets executed.

Comment: That still doesn't matter. Your code as it stands has no way of handling dead ends.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting stuck because your path-finding algorithm is unable to backtrack. What if you end up at a dead-end (i.e., wall to the front of you, left of you, and right of you)? You need the ability to backtrack.

From what I see, you are checking to see if the way to the right is blocked. If so, you move forward. But you need to check to see if you *can* move forward. Just because the way to the right is blocked, it doesn't mean that the way forward is open!

Furthermore, your third condition *never* gets executed, because the very first condition will report true for that and therefore the code within that `if` block will get executed.

Answer (score 1):

You need some condition to turn the cursor around. Think about it like keeping your right hand constantly on the wall of the maze, if you get to a point where there is a wall ahead and to the right then you'd just turn around (that's what happens when you keep your hand on the right wall).

So effectively

```
var up = 1;
function makeMove()
{   
    if(isWall("Right", up) && !isWall("Forward", up))
    {
        move("Forward", up);
    }
    else if(!isWall("Right", up))
    {
        move("Right", up);
    }
    else
    {
        up = !up; makeMove();
    }
}
```

In response to your comment you could use some simple system to keep track of direction:

```
function move( direction, up ) {
    if ( ! up ) {
        if (direction == "Forward") { direction = "Backward"; }
        else if ( direction == "Backward" ) { direction = "Forward"; }
        else if ( direction == "Right" ) { direction = "Left"; }
        else { direction = "Right"; }
    }

    … Your current code
}
```

**Edit:** Added a switch for "turning around" to be simulated. The same code should also go at the top of `isWall()`

Comment: For the final else statement, I tried using else move("Backward") and it got me farther through the maze but then turned into the cursor moving back and forth between the same two points and not actually getting anywhere after that (if that makes sense)

Comment: move("Backward") won't work because you'll still be moving in the same direction. Think about it like this, you're walking forwards, there is a wall in front of you and to the right of you if you take a step back without turning then you'll just get back to the same spot next time.

Comment: I understand the concept of touching the wall with your right hand until you get to the end, the problem I'm still encountering though is how I can translate that final piece of information into the code. If I call the function to move("Backward") I'll just keep getting stuck in a loop, like you explained; so do I have to call another conditional that will cause the cursor to move another direction after moving backward?

Comment: thanks for all the help, it's definitely helped me understand this a lot more!

Comment: No worries, I've just made another edit, you should include the `if (!up)...` block in your `isWall()` function as well.

Answer (score -2):

This should solve any maze... Eventually.

```
var direction = ['Left', 'Forward', 'Right', 'Back'];
var isWall = function () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
};

function makeMove() {
    var dir = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    dir = direction[dir];
    alert(dir);

    if (!isWall(dir)) move(dir);
    else makeMove();
}

function move(dir) {
    // Go places
    if (!confirm('You moved, continue?')) return;

    if ("places" === "exit") alert("FREEEEDOOM!");
    else makeMove();
}

makeMove();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xcDLY/1/)**

**[DEMO WITH MAZE](http://jsfiddle.net/xcDLY/4/)**

Comment: This is absolute nonsense to a question that whilst basic doesn't deserve it.

Comment: Wow, why the downvote? Downvote if you find me an algorithm that can solve more mazes than this!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm pick one, but given that the maze is non-cyclical then the Wall flower is the simplest to implement and explain.

Comment: There's not a single algorithm in there that can solve more mazes than  this. Shame on you.